# cannot open file TCBVS2017D.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, opc, opc-da

I hope you're doing well.
I've been trying to build opc classic project using softing github opc classic sdk ( https://github.com/SoftingIndustrial/OPC-Classic-SDK ) in visual studio 2017. I had a few errors at first which I managed to solve but there is this one error that I couldn't get around! " cannot open file TCBVS2017D.lib ". Can you help me resolve this problem please?

Comment: Can not open a library usually means 1 or more of these: 1. The library is not named what you said or the path for the library you typed to tell your linker where to find the library is not correct, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, or 3. The library file is corrupt.

Comment: It would help if you gave as much context as possible about when this error occurs.

Comment: I suggest you to read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#CreateAppToRefTheLib), which covers how to use the lib.